# python datatime result a malformed string while using strptime

Tags: pypubsub, pyp

[04/10/2024:23:18:39] PUT  "/new/origin" HTTP/1.1 200 256

strptime method is resulting fatal during run

Comment: Please add code you've written so far.

Comment: Also tell us, what you expect

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this

```
      ee = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', i)[0]
      '''
      The Strftime() function is used to convert date and time 
      objects to their string representation. It takes one or 
       more inputs of formatted code and returns the string 
      representation 
      '''
      dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(ee, '%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:%S').strftime('%d/%m/%Y:%H:%M:NN')  
  if date in diversed.keys():
    d_v[date]=diversed[date]+1
    # print(diversed[date])
  else:
    diversed[date]=1
    # print("no duplicates")
print(diversed)
```

Comment: Please add this code to your question, it is not an answer